# Setting a limit for a normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Lets say there is a company of workers and the weekly overtime work of an employee follows a normal distribution. I know the standard deviation and mean. 
 Now the company with a view to reducing the cost of overtime work wishes to set a maximum weekly overtime allowance which should not be exceeded by more than a given number of employees.

My question is how can I go about finding this limit? My thinking was to use Feller's tail bound

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} x} e^{−x^2/2},$$

where $x$ is the given number of employees. Is this the right formula I should use?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function

Comment: So it’s the quantile function I should be looking at ?